# match a text that follows a special string

Tags: regex, pcre, regular-language

I have a problem with my regular expression, I am trying to extract a string/number/whatever after a special string.

I have this string:

> TEST     3098

There is 6 spaces between TEST and its value, but I am not quite sure if it is alway 6 spaces.
I am trying this regular expression  (PCRE)

```
(?<=TEST\s\s\s\s\s\s).*?(?=\s)
```

The result should be 3098. With my regular expression, I get the right result, but it is not strong enough, if the number of spaces changes I won't be able to extract it.
The lookbehind should be in a limited size.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `(?<=TEST\s+).*?(?=\s)`? TEST followed by 1 or many white spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
TEST\s*\K\S+
```

If the number of whitespaces should be set to some min/max number use a [*limiting quantifier*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), `\s{2,}` will match two or more, `\s{1,10}` will allow 1 to 10 whitespaces.

**Details**

- `TEST` - `TEST`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\K` - [**match reset operator**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that omits the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jaqAvU/1)

Comment: I didn't know about `\K`, so cool man. Here is the regex detail: https://regex101.com/r/YyaPNU/1